# Setting Up TFS Aggregator CLI on Azure Function App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-function-app, tfs-aggregator

I'm trying to set up a new instance of Aggregator CLI as an Azure function app. I've created the app on Azure and think I've installed Aggregator CLI, but don't know how to save my Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) Personal Access Token (PAT) to Aggregator in order for the app to authenticate against DevOps. To be clear, I am **not** trying to install the [server plugin](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator) (which requires an on-prem instance of TFS) nor am I trying to configure the [webhooks version](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator-webhooks) (which has been deprecated).

### What I've done so far

1. Created a new resource group on Azure
2. Created a function app on Azure with storage account and application insights
3. Created an Azure service principle
4. Assigned permissions to the Azure service principle
5. Downloaded FunctionRuntime.zip v0.9.8 from https://github.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli/releases
6. Deployed the code to the function app
7. Created a PAT in Azure DevOps

### Expected behaviour

I expect to be able to save the PAT to the `Aggregator_VstsToken` application setting on the function app, so that the app can authenticate against VSTS. [Setup.md](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli/blob/master/doc/setup.md) doesn't describe how to do this. I expect to see the application settings shown in [this screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli/master/doc/images/PAT-token-in-Function-configuration.png) on the app.

### Actual behaviour

There isn't an application setting called `Aggregator_VstsToken` on the function app. There aren't any other Aggregator-specific settings either.

### Environment

- Azure DevOps (VSTS) cloud
- Azure Function App

Comment: Do you see the app settings screen of the function app? If you can access it, add those settings and update the right value. It doesn't automatically add those setting from source to the app settings screen. Any settings you had in the source code is overridden by azure settings.

Comment: Thanks, Jeeva. I can see and edit the settings for the function app, and could add a setting for `Aggregator_VstsToken`, but then what about all the other app settings? I don't mind creating them all manually if required, but where would I get a complete list of all settings? I only know about this setting from a screenshot in [setup.md](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli/blob/master/doc/setup.md).

Comment: You should be able to find all other app settings from the source app you are trying to deploy. In this instance the aggregator.